# Evaluating null varible in boolean expression

Tags: spring-el

When I try to evaluate a **boolean expression** that contain a **variable with null value** or **evaluate a undefined variable**, the parser not work as I expected, it does not fail, rather than, it assume the null variable (or the undefined variable) as big negative number (I guess...).

**Here the Test class I wrote to show this:**

```
public class SpELTest {

    @Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void evaluateNullVariable() {
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

        StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
        context.setVariable("PERFORMANCE", null);

        Boolean result = (Boolean)parser.parseExpression("#PERFORMANCE < 100").getValue(context);

        assertTrue(result); // no expected result
    }

    @Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void evaluateUndefinedVariable() {
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

        Boolean result = (Boolean)parser.parseExpression("#UNDEFINED < 100").getValue();

        assertTrue(result); // no expected result
    }
}
```

any idea of this behavior or how to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

`"#PERFORMANCE == null ? false : #PERFORMANCE < 100"`

Comment: yes it works, but not what I need, because I have this formula to establish criteria for measuring an indicator and then evaluate it, and this formula has to be as simple as possible, so that the write someone who knows SpEL nothing.

Comment: I think i will to do something like you suggestion, because spel treat null values of that weird way